# Serve content from centralized location

Tags: cache, xml, sync

I'm looking for an easy/efficient way to manage & serve content from one master WP site to multiple drones (NOT multisite).

On the master site i'll have custom post type "served_content".
The drones will have "collection" pages, each will serve multiple different served_content posts.
served_content might become disabled from the master site, too.

### Requirements

- Fetch posts **with their metadata**
- Cache this data so we don't slow down
  page load too much. Ideally instead of requesting everytime, it can just **sync** the "served_content" posts across all my WP installations
- Use mostly native WP functions, or readymade WP
  plugins
- Being able to publish **and un-publish** (disable from showing) the served-content, right **from the master site**.

### How I want it to work

On (one of) my clients i'll have a page that requests specific post IDs from the centralized location, for example:

```
$posts_to_retrieve = array(1,5,12,23);
get_remote_posts($posts_to_retrieve);
```

### What I've been planning on using

- WP XML-RPC api (and specifically wp.getPost method)
- SimpleXML to parse the returned XML

The problem is I don't think XML-RPC method is caching the requests

What will you recommend to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I don't think XML-RPC method is caching the requests". I don't think it should. If you're caching the responses on your "drone" sites, then you needn't worry about it - they'll only "ping" the master site once every X hours (however long you decide to cache the response for).

Comment: So yuo're saying I should just use XML-RPC and some caching plugin (e.g. W3 Total Cache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your master site, [register a new XML RPC method](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) that accepts a date argument and replies back with all content published *since* then.

For each of your drone sites, [register a cron hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) that pings the master every X minutes/hours with the date of the most recently "imported" content, and then saves the response locally.

W3 Total Cache (and the like) are *front-end* cache systems for serving up content to your users. In this context, caching is referring to storing content on the drone site for a period of time, and then updating at regular intervals, as opposed to pinging the master on every front-end request.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer!
How does the drone site imports the data? Will it create it in the wp_post table?
Also, What happens if one of the original posts that was imported, was unpublished in the master site?
The content may be published and un-published anytime - so this is something to take into account (I've added this req to the original questions, sorry I didn't mention it before)

Comment: Yes, I'd create the posts in `wp_posts` so that they behave in the same way on the drone site. Your second question is a bit beyond the scope of WPSE - I can help steer you in the right direction, but I can't code it for you!

Comment: You're right, I did some homework (post_status is the answer to my second question), so please let me be more specific :) :
since posts ids can't be synced between the setups, I need to find a way to put a reference to the original id in the master site. I'm thinking of using the guid field for that purpose, is that a good idea? Or maybe a custom field? Any suggestion?

Comment: I would use a custom (meta) field.